# PHP structure with Composer does not work

Tags: php, composer-php

Good morning, people!
I'm having the following problem in my projectx in php:

I created a project with Composer in php where I put php to listen to the public folder from the command prompt. However, when I upload the project to the site or to the xampp htdocs, the result of displaying the index (domain / projectx / public) is white. It does not display anything or any warning. Running with the php server via prompt listening directly to the public folder the project runs normally.

The structure of the project is this (it has an attached image too):

```
projeto x
    -App
        -Controller (folder with controllers)
        -Model (folder with models)
        -View (folder with views)
        -Connection (DB connection class)
        -Route (Class that manages the routes accessed in the browser and instantiates the necessary controllers)
    -public
        -.htaccess
        -index.php (Application start page that instantiates the Route class to determine the flow of the application)
    -vendor
        -composer (folder with composer files)
        -autoload.php
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    composer.phar
```

When I include files in the public folder and access directly, the file works normally. That is, the server is listening to all folders.

Could you help me with this? If I have to configure something on the server or in my project? I am new to PHP and would greatly appreciate your help.

Right now, I'm grateful!

Application running on the latest version of Composer.
Tested on php version 5.6.40 and 7.1

[project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sZUX.jpg)

Comment: are you using a php framework or it's custom?

Comment: Are you testing locally? is your web server running?

Comment: Good night!

The context is that I use a shared hosting, and the folder available to the project is not the root of hosting.
I researched other topics and will try to make some settings in the hosting tomorrow.
I will come back with the results to share with you.
I am from Brazil and our time zones should be different. Sorry for the divergence.

My sincere thanks from now on.

I hope to see you again and continue to help me on this journey.

Big hug!

Comment: I do not use any frameworks. Composer only.
The tests were done by starting with the php -S command inside the public folder of the project saved locally on the computer.
The php version tested is 5.6 and 7.1.
In online production that did not work.

Comment: I got past the blank page. It was a composer installation error on the server.
However, I can access my index, but it does not pass to the other URLs declared in my Route.php.
What other setting do I need to set on the server?
Locally the design runs smoothly.